# First and second order conditions - show that they are equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Function $ f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ , given by $ f(x)=(1/2)x^T P x + q^T x + r$, where $P\succeq 0$, Prove this first and second order conditions are equivalent.

In S.Boyd's lecture:

1. First-order: f is convex if $f(y)\geq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)$
2. Second-order: f is convex if Hessian $\geq 0$

My attempt:

**Second order:** Calculate Hessian.

$$
\nabla f(x) = \frac12(P+P^T)x+ q = Px+q
$$

$$
\nabla^2 f(x) = P 
$$

If $P\succeq 0$, then convex (Okay, so far).

Now, **How do I do the same with the first-order?**

I know that first-order and second-order are equivalent. How I do?

My attempt:

**First-order**: $f(y)\geq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)$

Then,

$$
f(y)\geq (1/2)x^T P x + q^T x + r+ (Px+q)^T(y-x)
$$

**I have difficulty simplifying first order**

Comment: You have expressions for $f(x)$ and $\nabla f(x)$, so substitute those into the first-order condition equation.

Comment: @Joe, $$f(y)\geq (1/2)x^T P x + q^T x + (Px+q)(y-x)$$, My question is how do I show that first and second order are equivalent

Comment: Why do you think you are supposed to show that they are equivalent?  I think you are only supposed to show that both conditions are satisfied.  Use the definition of $f$ to substitute for the $f(y)$, then simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
f(y) - f(x) - \nabla f(x)(y-x) \ge 0
$$

$$
\varepsilon  = \frac12 (y-x)^TP(y-x)\ge 0
$$

Now, you demonstrate the derivative and find P.